# Is there way to programmatically obtain URL of File related to sObject?

Tags: formula-field, files, image-formula

This is for my pet project.

I have a `Candidate` object and image from related files should be displayed on it's record page. I know that it is possible to display image using formula field, but for that I need link to this file.

Is it possible to programmatically obtain this file URL to store in the object field and then use it in formula field?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use apex to get all the related files(ContentDocuments) attached to any record.

In apex controller you can pass any record id to the function.

```
public static String getRelatedFileURLById (String recordId) {
     try { 
          List <ContentDocumentLink> CDLs = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM 
          ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId = :recordId];

          if (CDLs.size() < 1) {
              return '';
          }
          else {
          //In case you only want the first file's URL in case there are more than 
          one files attached to this record.
                return '/lightning/r/ContentDocument'+CDLs[0].ContentDocuemntId+'/view';
            }        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
}
```

And then in javascript controller, you can call another apex controller to update the field with url for the specific record.

Comment: this method works to obtain link for file preview page, not for the image itself.
Link for the image itself that can be used in formula field  looks like that 

`https://cunning-unicorn-luyqex-dev-ed.file.force.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=ORIGINAL_Jpg&versionId=0687Q000005V6In&operationContext=CHATTER&contentId=05T7Q00000L9l1s`

Comment: I cant see this link. Its your orgs link.

Comment: This is only example of how the link has to look in order to be used to display picture in formula field.